# fluent validation - How to loop through List<string>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

This is my xml :

```
  <recordset>
  <!-- multiple value record-->
  <record>
    <KeyName>aliases</KeyName>
    <KeyValue>
      
      <val>VENKAT</val>
      <val>vraja</val>
    </KeyValue>
  </record>


  <!-- single value record-->
  <record>
    <KeyName>accountType</KeyName>
    <KeyValue>

      <val>ADM</val>
    </KeyValue>
  </record>
</recordset>
```

this is my equivalent C# class for the XML.

```
public class Record
{
    public string KeyName { get; set; }
    public KeyValue KeyValue { get; set; }
}

public class Recordset
{
    public List<Record> Record { get; set; }
}
```

Now using fluent validation I am trying to validate every record in my record set.

SchemaValidator.cs

```
public class SchemaValidator : AbstractValidator<Entity.EigenData.Recordset>
{
    public SchemaValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(rec => rec.Record[0]).NotNull().SetValidator(new RecordValidator());
    }
}
```

RecordValidator.cs

```
public class RecordValidator : AbstractValidator<Entity.EigenData.Record>
{
    public RecordValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(rec => rec.KeyName).NotNull();
        RuleFor(rec => rec.KeyValue).NotNull();
    }
}
```

note :I am able to validate only first record

ie., `RuleFor(rec => rec.Record[0]).NotNull().SetValidator(new RecordValidator());`

How will I validate for all records in the recordset?

I tried

`RuleFor(rec => rec.Record).NotNull().SetValidator(new RecordValidator());`
but got conversion error

Program.cs

```
 //Note: Recordset contains many List<record>
 private static void Validate(Entity.EigenData.Recordset recordset)
 {
     SchemaValidator validator = new SchemaValidator();

     ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(recordset);

     if (!results.IsValid)
     {
         foreach (var failure in results.Errors)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Property " + failure.PropertyName + " failed validation. Error was: " + failure.ErrorMessage);
         }
     }
     // throw new NotImplementedException();
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count it using **RuleForEach**

```
public class SchemaValidator : AbstractValidator<Entity.EigenData.Recordset>
{
    public SchemaValidator()
    {   
        RuleForEach(rec => rec.Record).NotNull().SetValidator(new RecordValidator());
    }
}
```